# MongoDB: ObjectId to String

Tags: php, mongodb

Hello everyone I use MongoDB find() method like this:

```
$cursor = $collection->find();
foreach($cursor as $doc) {
   // do something....
}
```

it's ok but my _id property is autogenereted so when I use code above $doc[_id] is Object but I need a string.

How can I convert it to string automatically. Not like this:

```
foreach($cursor as $doc) {      
    $doc['_id'] = (string)$doc['_id'];
}
```

Comment: Why do you need it to be a string? In most cases where a string is needed (`echo`ing, etc.) the object's `__toString()` will be called automatically. In any case, don't overwrite the `$doc` object's `_id` with a string.

Comment: @user1006884: Actually, casting should work. What's the problem?

Comment: I use this: json_encode($doc); so I don't use echo.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Handling mongoid properly by `json_encode` used to be [a bug in the php driver](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/PHP-154). It should be fixed since v1.0.11.

Answer (score 3):

To automaticaly convert ObjectId to string from any result from the MongoDB-driver I use this function:

```
function convertMongoIds(array &$array){
    foreach ($array as &$element){
        if (is_array($element)){
            convertMongoIds($element);
        }else if (is_object($element) && get_class($element) == "MongoId"){
            $element = (string) $element;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

```
`$result = $collection->findOne([
     '_id' => new \MongoDB\BSON\ObjectId("5a59b11b3ffd3aec4a23cd2c")
]);


var_dump((string)$result->_id, $result->_id->__toString());`
```

Both work in version 3.6.

**[reference](http://php.net/manual/en/mongodb-bson-objectid.tostring.php)**