# Convert ObjectID (Mongodb) to String in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, mongodb, aggregation-framework

I want to convert ObjectID (Mongodb) to String in JavaScript.
When I get a Object form MongoDB. it like as a object has: timestamp, second, inc, machine.
I can't convert to string.

Comment: `""+objectId` or `objectId.toString()` whereby `objectId` is the variable I believe will do what your looking for.

Comment: ObjectID loaded from MongoDB is a Object. if you use toString() function in Javascript, It will return [Object, Object].

Comment: Odd, those functions were supposed to be implemented, I am sure that was fixed

Comment: Dunno who marked this a duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8106517/mongodb-objectid-to-string but you are seriously wrong...

Comment: I think it's not bad question.!
Your link is used for PHP. I need it in JavaScript.!

Comment: Indeed fortunately the stuff below is javascript :)

Comment: @vhlen what worked for you? 
i am also getting [Object, Object]

Comment: I think there is some confusion in the answers as to whether you are talking about the mongodb console, or the javascript driver for node (both are JS, but are not identical in usage unfortunately)

Answer (score 132):

Try this:

```js
// mongo shell
objectId.str

// mongo client, JS, Node.js
objectId.toString()
```

See the [doc](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/object-id/).

> `ObjectId()` has the following attribute and methods:
>
> - `str` - Returns the hexadecimal string representation of the object.

`.toString()` added from comment of @J.C.

Comment: i dont understand why, this isnt working for me
when i do a console.log, i see the objectId as an object on the console

Comment: This didn't work for me either. However, `objectId.toString()` did.

Comment: `objectId.str` is for mongo shell, `objectId.toString()` is for mongo client

Comment: What is the solution for monk? Neither .str or .toString() are working I am just getting an object, where the display is the exact string I am after but doesn't match equality checks against another string

Answer (score 30):

Here is a working example of converting the `ObjectId` in to a string

```
> a=db.dfgfdgdfg.findOne()
{ "_id" : ObjectId("518cbb1389da79d3a25453f9"), "d" : 1 }
> a['_id']
ObjectId("518cbb1389da79d3a25453f9")
> a['_id'].toString // This line shows you what the prototype does
function () {
    return "ObjectId(" + tojson(this.str) + ")";
}
> a['_id'].str // Access the property directly
518cbb1389da79d3a25453f9
> a['_id'].toString()
ObjectId("518cbb1389da79d3a25453f9") // Shows the object syntax in string form
> ""+a['_id'] 
518cbb1389da79d3a25453f9 // Gives the hex string
```

Did try various other functions like `toHexString()` with no success.

Comment: .toHexString() worked for me thanks Sammaye! http://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/api-bson-generated/objectid.html

Comment: As of 2022 there's no .str - the only viable way to convert an ObjectId to String is through .toString()

Answer (score 29):

in the [shell](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/ObjectId/)

`ObjectId("507f191e810c19729de860ea").str`

in js [using the native driver for node](http://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/2.0/api/ObjectID.html)

`objectId.toHexString()`

Comment: Nice answer, which points out the difference using native driver.

Comment: This is the case if you're using a client like NoSQLBooster. Thanks.

Answer (score 16):

You can use [**`$toString`**](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/toString/) aggregation introduced in mongodb version **4.0** which converts the ObjectId to string

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  { "$project": {
    "_id": { "$toString": "$your_objectId_field" }
  }}
])
```

Answer (score 10):

Use toString:
`var stringId = objectId.toString()`

Works with the latest Node MongoDB Native driver (v3.0+):

http://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/3.0/

Answer (score 9):

Acturally, you can try this:

```
> a['_id']
ObjectId("518cbb1389da79d3a25453f9")
> a['_id'] + ''
"518cbb1389da79d3a25453f9"
```

ObjectId object + String will convert to String object.

Answer (score 8):

## If someone use in Meteorjs, can try:

In server: `ObjectId(507f191e810c19729de860ea)._str`.

In template: `{{ collectionItem._id._str }}`.

Answer (score 6):

Assuming the OP wants to get the hexadecimal string value of the ObjectId, using Mongo 2.2 or above, the `valueOf()` method returns the representation of the object as a hexadecimal string. This is also achieved with the `str` property.

The link on anubiskong's post gives all the details, the danger here is to use a technique which has changed from older versions e.g. `toString()`.

Answer (score 6):

In Javascript, String() make it easy

```
const id = String(ObjectID)
```

Answer (score 5):

this works, You have mongodb object: `ObjectId(507f191e810c19729de860ea)`,
to get string value of `_id`, you just say

```
ObjectId(507f191e810c19729de860ea).valueOf();
```

Comment: Please improve your answer

Comment: the string is wrapped inside ObjectId, so to get the wrapped value you use the answer i  just provided @ Ivan Barayev

Answer (score 3):

In Js do simply: `_id.toString()`

For example:

```
const myMongoDbObjId = ObjectID('someId');
const strId = myMongoDbObjId.toString();
console.log(typeof strId); // string
```

Comment: needs some explanation

Comment: @sidgate, added an example

Comment: Thanks @Mar this just save me from a serialization bug.

Answer (score 1):

You can use string formatting.

```js
const stringId = `${objectId}`;
```

Answer (score 1):

`toString()` method gives you hex String which is kind of ascii code but in base 16 number system.

> Converts the id into a 24 character hex string for printing

For example in this system:

```
"a" -> 61
"b" -> 62
"c" -> 63
```

So if you pass `"abc..."` to get `objectId` you will get "616263...".

As a result if you want to get readable string(char string) from `objectId` you have to convert it(hexCode to char).

To do this I wrote an utility function `hexStringToCharString()`

```
function hexStringToCharString(hexString) {
  const hexCodeArray = [];

  for (let i = 0; i < hexString.length - 1; i += 2) {
    hexCodeArray.push(hexString.slice(i, i + 2));
  }

  const decimalCodeArray = hexCodeArray.map((hex) => parseInt(hex, 16));

  return String.fromCharCode(...decimalCodeArray);
}
```

and there is usage of the function

```
import { ObjectId } from "mongodb";

const myId = "user-0000001"; // must contains 12 character for "mongodb": 4.3.0
const myObjectId = new ObjectId(myId); // create ObjectId from string

console.log(myObjectId.toString()); // hex string >> 757365722d30303030303031
console.log(myObjectId.toHexString()); // hex string >> 757365722d30303030303031

const convertedFromToHexString = hexStringToCharString(
  myObjectId.toHexString(),
);

const convertedFromToString = hexStringToCharString(myObjectId.toString());

console.log(`convertedFromToHexString:`, convertedFromToHexString);
//convertedFromToHexString: user-0000001
console.log(`convertedFromToString:`, convertedFromToString);
//convertedFromToHexString: user-0000001
```

And there is also **TypeScript** version of hexStringToCharString() function

```
function hexStringToCharString(hexString: string): string {
  const hexCodeArray: string[] = [];

  for (let i = 0; i < hexString.length - 1; i += 2) {
    hexCodeArray.push(hexString.slice(i, i + 2));
  }

  const decimalCodeArray: number[] = hexCodeArray.map((hex) =>
    parseInt(hex, 16),
  );

  return String.fromCharCode(...decimalCodeArray);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use this : `_id.$oid`

And you get the ObjectId string. This come with the object.

Comment: You can see that at [Strict MongoDB Extended JSON](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/mongodb-extended-json/#oid).

Answer (score 0):

Found this really funny but it worked for me:

```
    db.my_collection.find({}).forEach((elm)=>{

    let value = new String(elm.USERid);//gets the string version of the ObjectId which in turn changes the datatype to a string.

    let result = value.split("(")[1].split(")")[0].replace(/^"(.*)"$/, '$1');//this removes the objectid completely and the quote 
    delete elm["USERid"]
    elm.USERid = result
    db.my_collection.save(elm)
    })
```

Comment: Hello Hogan jerry, and welcome to StackOverflow! Please use code formatting only for the code parts, it will be easier to read :) Have a good day!

Comment: Thanks... was too excited

Answer (score 0):

**On aggregation use $addFields**

```
$addFields: {
      convertedZipCode: { $toString: "$zipcode" }
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

Documentation of v4 (right now it's latest version) MongoDB NodeJS Driver says: Method toHexString() of ObjectId returns the ObjectId id as a 24 character hex string representation.

Answer (score 0):

In Mongoose, you can use toString() method on ObjectId to get a 24-character hexadecimal string.

[Mongoose documentation](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/5.x/docs/schematypes.html#objectids)

Answer (score 0):

Below three methods can be used to get the string version of id.

(Here newUser is an object containing the data to be stored in the mongodb document)

```
newUser.save((err, result) => {
  if (err) console.log(err)
  else {
     console.log(result._id.toString()) //Output - 23f89k46546546453bf91
     console.log(String(result._id))    //Output - 23f89k46546546453bf91
     console.log(result._id+"")         //Output - 23f89k46546546453bf91
  }
});
```

Answer (score -1):

Use this simple trick, `your-object.$id`

I am getting an array of mongo Ids, here is what I did.

jquery:

```
...
success: function (res) {
   console.log('without json res',res);
    //without json res {"success":true,"message":" Record updated.","content":[{"$id":"58f47254b06b24004338ffba"},{"$id":"58f47254b06b24004338ffbb"}],"dbResponse":"ok"}

var obj = $.parseJSON(res);

if(obj.content !==null){
    $.each(obj.content, function(i,v){
        console.log('Id==>', v.$id);
    });
}

...
```

Answer (score -1):

You could use `String`

```
String(a['_id'])
```

Answer (score -2):

If you're using [Mongoose](https://mongoosejs.com/) along with MongoDB, it has a built-in method for getting the string value of the ObjectID. I used it successfully to do an `if` statement that used `===` to compare strings.

From the [documentation](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/guide.html#id):

> Mongoose assigns each of your schemas an id virtual getter by default which returns the document's _id field cast to a string, or in the case of ObjectIds, its hexString. If you don't want an id getter added to your schema, you may disable it by passing this option at schema construction time.