# How do I access the 'str' value in my object?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to return the value under the key 'str' in an Object but I am having trouble accessing the value.

This is what is returned in the console:

[image]

Currently I am using a map function to go over the array and just return the _str value like so:

```
let idx = currentArray.map(function(x) {
            return x._id._str;
        });
```

However it is still returning the value as an object. How can I get just the value of the _str key?

Here is the full array without specifying the id field. This is what is returned if you jsut return 'x' in the map function.

[image]

Comment: it looks like the object is an array, so try `x[0]._id._str`

Comment: there is no _id property in your image

Comment: That is what is returned when I do x._id

I can show you the full array if you would like.

Comment: @Our_Benefactors unfortunately that returned undefined. I've added a picture of the full array when you just return x. Maybe that might shed more light on it?

Comment: @RP12 edited my original comment based on the new screenshot

Comment: @Our_Benefactors Getting the error '_id is not defined'

Comment: @RP12 do document.write(JSON.stringify(currentArray)) and post that

Comment: @RP12 what is the message when you do `console.log(x[0])` ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Convert ObjectID (Mongodb) to String in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16478552/convert-objectid-mongodb-to-string-in-javascript)

Comment: @Our_Benefactors: Why suggest stumbling around in the dark with a `console.log` torch? Instead, suggest *turning on the lights* by using the debugger built into the browser.

Comment: @Our_Benefactors Apologies that earlier error said str was not defined.

So I did x[0] and it gave me an array with one object that said 0:undefined

Comment: Note that `x` is not an array, but an object. If using `[0]` would access an array. Use `['0']` instead. Using it in full would look like: `x['0']._id._str`

Comment: @T.J.Crowder because it's not clear WTF is going on. Especially when OP keeps providing incorrect information.

Comment: @Our_Benefactors Sorry I did correct the info when I found it.

Comment: @Our_Benefactors: Right. Which is where the debugger, rather than `console.log`, can make things a lot clearer.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder I don't have access to the debugger for this data.

Comment: @Our_Benefactors: **You** don't, but the OP does. I'm just saying: Suggesting `console.log` is a **lot** less useful than suggesting using a proper debugger. (Apologies for the mixup there.)

Answer (score 0):

You've clarified that the screenshot is of `x._id`. So to access `_str`, you'd use `x._id[0]._str`: The `_str` property is in the object referenced by the `0` property (the first entry in the array `x._id` refers to).

---

Note that in general, `_`-prefixed properties are meant not to be accessed by code outside the code responsible for the objects in question. You don't seem to be responsible for them, so accessing those properties is likely to make your code rely on undocumented properties that may change in the next "dot" release of whatever lib you're using. It's just convention, but it's a **very** common convention.

Comment: Unfortunately I got an 'undefined' when I tried x._id[0]._str

I uploaded the full array, maybe that will explain why I got the undefined value?

Comment: @RP12: At the end of the day, you just have to figure it out with your debugger. Set a breakpoint on the line, and then inspect the object the `x` variable refers to. Don't stumble around in the dark with a `console.log` torch; *turn on the lights* by using the debugger.

Answer (score 0):

If you right click on the property, most browser consoles offer the ability to `copy property path`.

Answer (score 0):

Based on [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16478552/convert-objectid-mongodb-to-string-in-javascript) and [the docs](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/ObjectId/), it appears that you can probably use `x._id.str`.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you are receiving the str value but it is an object instead of the string literal. In other words, you are getting `_str: "598..."` instead of `"598...."`. A possible solution would be to use the mongo javascript function to convert the str value to a string.

In your case, I think something like `return x._id.str;` may work as `_id` is a MongoID.ObjectID.

I've also linked the documentation below for reference.

https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/ObjectId/

Here's a relevant SO answer as well: [Convert ObjectID (Mongodb) to String in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16478552/convert-objectid-mongodb-to-string-in-javascript)

Answer (score -2):

I think you should write `x[_id]._str` because `_id` is one of the array objects.

Comment: This is not even valid sintax

Comment: @juvian: Yes it is. It's not relevant to the question, but it's valid syntax (note the spelling). It looks up a property in `x` using the contents of the variable `_id`, then looks up the `_str` property on the result of that.

Comment: There is no _id variable, that´s a property of x

Comment: @juvian Right. (As I said above: It's not relevant to the question, but it's valid syntax.)