# Scripting MongoDB shell, return ID in clean format

Tags: javascript, json, mongodb

The script below is supposed to return a CSV of values I want from mongo, all the data I want is returned, but two items are in a different format, and try as I might I cannot get the value only.
**Question 1:** The first returned item "$_id", returns ObjectId("5a4b7775d9cc09000185b908")  but I want to get ONLY the value 5a4b7775d9cc09000185b908. Every time I try to parse it or use valueOf, it returns a blank value.

**Question 2:** The 4th item I am requesting is supposed to be a time format of how long something took using the two date values {$subtract: [ "$finished", "$started" ] } (start and finish times). What I get back is NumberLong(5844) which should be just the milisenconds.

**Script**

```
var cur=db.submissions.aggregate(
[
    {$match: { started: {'$gte': ISODate('2018-01-02 01:01:01.001'), '$lte': ISODate('2018-01-02 13:15:59.999' ) } } },
    {$project: { 
        data: [
    "$_id",
    {$dateToString: { format: "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S", date: "$started" } },
    {$dateToString: { format: "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S", date: "$finished" } },
    {$subtract: [ "$finished", "$started" ] },
    "$inputs.x12InputFile.size"
           ] 
        }
    }
]
)
cur.forEach(function(doc) {print(doc.data)})
```

**Current Results**

```
ObjectId("5a4b7775d9cc09000185b908"),2018-01-02 12:13:42,2018-01-02 12:13:48,NumberLong(5844),5322
ObjectId("5a4b77d530391100017d92df"),2018-01-02 12:15:18,2018-01-02 12:15:26,NumberLong(8593),5178
```

**Expected Results**

```
5a4b7775d9cc09000185b908,2018-01-02 12:13:42,2018-01-02 12:13:48,5844,5322
5a4b77d530391100017d92df,2018-01-02 12:15:18,2018-01-02 12:15:26,8593,5178
```

Any help would be appreciated. I am quite the newbie at scripting mongo queries, so details/examples in responses help if at all possible.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Convert ObjectID (Mongodb) to String in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16478552/convert-objectid-mongodb-to-string-in-javascript)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I wouldn't use aggregation framework for formatting results. You can't convert from ObjectId  to string in aggregation piepline anyways.

```
var cursor = db.submissions.find({started:{'$gte': ISODate('2018-01-02 
01:01:01.001'),'$lte': ISODate('2018-01-02 13:15:59.999' )}},{started : 1, 
finished : 1, "inputs.inputFile.size" : 1});

cursor.forEach( function(doc) { 
    var arr=[];
    arr.push(doc._id.str);
    arr.push(doc.started.toISOString());
    arr.push(doc.finished.toISOString());
    arr.push(doc.finished.getTime() - doc.started.getTime());
    print(arr)
});
```

Comment: This is amazing and almost exactly what I was looking for, however this doesn't have an option to push the "inputs.inputFile.size" . I have tried several options to print that out, but I am either missing the correct way to print it, ot I am calling in in an incorrect way. Do you know the simple answer here?

Comment: Did not work for me. thank you for looking into this. Will check back for updated answer

Comment: Updated with JSON... As you can see I need to get the value of inputs.inputFile.size out of mongo and get that printed with the array.

Comment: Something like      `arr.push(doc.inputs.inputFile.size);`

Comment: You won't believe me when I tell you this, but I tried that exact thing a hundred different ways and it failed. This time it worked. I looked back and fat fingered a value...  Thank you so much!