# Convert ObjectId to String in the MongoDB

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I have an aggregate query.

```
{ "$addFields": {
  "collegeID": (('$collegeDetail._id')),
}}
```

where, I want to add a new field **'CollegeID'** as a string version of the ObjectId stored in collegeDetail._id.

Any help will be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: This is not currently supported, but will be available in an upcoming release. See [here](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-29512).

Comment: Isn't there any workaround possible?

Comment: I can't see anything out there - all solutions talk of doing it in the JavaScript context, outside of an aggregation pipeline, which I guess is not what you are looking for.

Comment: Exactly. Will scavenge more about it. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Edit: Starting from (Version 4.0 of MongoDB) Gladly MongoDB has made and update and got us a new operator that does this job.

$convert

This can be used to change the data type of value from almost each type to each type

For more information check it up here: **https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/convert/**

Hope this helps;

Answer (score 3):

You should try  [**`$toString`**](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/toString/) aggregation to convert ObjectId to string

```
db.strcoll.aggregate([
  { "$addFields": {
    "collegeID": { "$toString": "$collegeDetail._id" }
  }}
])
```

Answer (score 1):

The Link below will provide you javascript way to convert objectId to string:
[Convert ObjectID (Mongodb) to String in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16478552/convert-objectid-mongodb-to-string-in-javascript)

Comment: Thanks for the help, but as you see in the question I wanted to do it in the query itself.