# Difference of 2 array of objects when id's are not the same

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have 2 arrays, `arr1` retrieved from a db and `arr2` sent as a request body. I'm trying to get the difference between both arrays but I get an error because the `id` from the db isn't a string. How do I stringify the `id` within the array so I can properly filter?

```
arr1 = [
   { id: 125ddgs34, name: ‘dgsgs’  }, 
   { id: 356kfjj1235, name: ‘adhkdh’  }, 
   { id: 87hjsgffjj, name: ‘fshjyy’  }, 
]

arr2 = [
  { id: ‘125ddgs34’, name: ‘dgsgs’  }, 
  { id: ‘356kfjj1235’, name: ‘adhkdh’  }, 
]

let difference = arr1.filter(x => !arr2.some(x2 => {
    console.log(x.id, "=========")
    console.log((x2.id, "======"))
}));
```

Comment: `arr1` is a syntax error. How are you making it from the DB?

Comment: yeah. It's an ObjectId from a mongo db @MarkMeyer

Comment: `125ddgs34` is not a valid javascript value.

Comment: I wonder if this might be helpful @Hopez: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16478552/convert-objectid-mongodb-to-string-in-javascript

Comment: @MarkMeyer Was very helpful. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you are using 'mongodb', try this :

```
arr1 = [
   { id: ObjectId("507f1f77bcf86cd799439011"), name: ‘dgsgs’  }, 
   { id: ObjectId("507f1f77bcf86cd799439012"), name: ‘adhkdh’  }, 
   { id: ObjectId("507f1f77bcf86cd799439013"), name: ‘fshjyy’  }, 
]
```

Comment: The data is retrieved from mongo as written in my question. I need to automatically make it a string