# Can't convert ObjectId to String in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, reactjs, mongodb, fetch-api, objectid

Having trouble converting an `objectID` to a string in react after fetching my API...
I can't get this for instance "ObjectId(5e23828631c3f20fd40d3feb)".
I just need this "5e23828631c3f20fd40d3feb"
Here is my code:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import jwt_decode from 'jwt-decode'
import ObjectID from 'bson-objectid'

class Profile extends Component {
    constructor() {
        super()
        this.state = {
            full_name: '',
            username: '',
            email: '',
            pubCount: '',
            abmnCount: '',
            abneCount: '',
            errors: {}
        }
        this.loadProfile = this.loadProfile.bind(this)
    }

    loadProfile(){

        const token = localStorage.usertoken
        fetch('http://localhost:9000/kotgram/user/mesinfos', {
            method: 'get',
            headers: new Headers({
                'Authorization': token,
                'Content-Type': 'application/json'
            })
        }).then(res => res.json())
            .then(data => {
                console.log(data._id.toString()) /*this shows [object][object] when I try to convert it to a string. I tried to import bson-objectid but it doesnt work*/
                console.log(data.email)
                this.setState({
                    full_name: data.full_name,
                    username: data.username,
                    email: data.email,
                    pubCount: data.pubCount,
                    abmnCount: data.abmnCount,
                    abneCount: data.abneCount
                })                
            })
            .catch(error => console.log('ERROR'));
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        this.loadProfile()

        
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div className="container">
                <div className="jumbotron mt-5">
                    <div className="col-sm-8 mx-auto">
                        <h1 className="text-center">PROFILE</h1>
                    </div>
                    <table className="table col-md-6 mx-auto">
                        <tbody>
                        <tr>
                            <td>Nom complet</td>
                            <td>{this.state.full_name}</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>Username</td>
                            <td>{this.state.username}</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>Email</td>
                            <td>{this.state.email}</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>Publications</td>
                            <td>{this.state.pubCount}</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>Abe</td>
                            <td>{this.state.abneCount}</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>Abn</td>
                            <td>{this.state.abmnCount}</td>
                        </tr>
                        </tbody>
                    </table>
                </div>
            </div>
        )
    }
}

export default Profile
```

I've use Kotlin for my backend Server and MongoDB to store my collections..
Please Help..

Comment: Can you console log data._id, If it is an object take the value from proper key. If you want to convert an object to string use JSON.stringify()

Comment: When i console.log(data._id) I get this `Object { timestamp: 1579386476, counter: 3838245, time: 1579386476000, date: "2020-01-18T22:27:56.000+0000", timeSecond: 1579386476, processIdentifier: 9618, machineIdentifier: 14360163 }
Profile.js:37
` There's no way I can access the ObjectId parameter

Comment: Then you can take any of these properties as your `objectId` which I assume you just make sure it's unique, ex. `data._id.processIdentifier`.

Comment: Thanks. Actually I cant do that because my rest Controller requires an objectID.. Here I'm trying to get this ObjectId and pass it to another url of another API. When I put an existing objectId into postman everything works fine, I can fetch my user but when I'm trying to do the same thing in React I cant get any further with my request because I cant get the value of the "_id" parameter which should be an hexString..

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Convert ObjectID (Mongodb) to String in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16478552/convert-objectid-mongodb-to-string-in-javascript)

Comment: Nope, it did not but I found another way; I replace my objectId with a string that stores an hexadecimal value of my ObjectId

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just found a solution:
I went back to my backend server and I replace this 
`@Id val _id: ObjectId?`
with this
`@Id val _id: String = ObjectId().toHexString()` So that I'll only have the value of the objectId as an "hexString" instead of having others parameters like "machineIdentifier" or "processIdentifier"