# How to convert Array of ObjectID to Array of string?

Tags: javascript

I have a array of objectID like this-

```
 [
    new ObjectId("62bab157e769a7dda09ec63f"),
    new ObjectId("62bab15ce769a7dda09ec64a"),
    new ObjectId("62bab164e769a7dda09ec657")
 ]
```

Now I need to get result like this-

```
[
  '62bab157e769a7dda09ec63f',
  '62bab15ce769a7dda09ec64a',
  '62bab164e769a7dda09ec657'
]
```

I need the conversion function in one line just. Please help me.

Comment: Use the `ObjectID.toString()` method.

Comment: How does function/class `ObjectId` look like?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour] if you haven't already (you get a badge!) and read through the [help], in particular [*How do I ask a good question?*](/help/how-to-ask) Aside from the issue of lack of detail, your best bet here is to do your research, [search](/help/searching) for related topics on SO and elsewhere, and give it a go. ***If*** you get stuck and can't get unstuck after doing more research and searching, post a [mre] showing your attempt and say specifically where you're stuck. People will be glad to help.

Comment: Is this supposed to be a MongoDb `ObjectId` ...? You should at least properly tag the question then. And then: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map

Comment: Also, is `ObjectId` the one from MongoDB? If so, this is a duplicate of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16478552/convert-objectid-mongodb-to-string-in-javascript). [Please search thoroughly](/search?q=%5Bmongodb%5D+%5Bjs%5D+convert+ObjectId+to+string) before posting. More about searching [here](/help/searching).

Answer (score 0):

```js
let object =  [
    new Object("62bab157e769a7dda09ec63f"),
    new Object("62bab15ce769a7dda09ec64a"),
    new Object("62bab164e769a7dda09ec657")
 ];
let objectString = object.toString();
let stringArray = objectString.split(",");
console.log(stringArray);
```

Answer (score -1):

i think ObjectId is custom constractor if it is you have write method return that id and you can call that method where you need

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).